# Synchronize wordpress site between two different servers

Tags: multisite, content, multi-language, hosting, sync

This is my situation:

I have a wordpress website on *server A hosted in Belgium*. It's a multilingual website available in languages: Dutch, French, English. I also need the language *Vietnamese*. The wordpress website for Vietnamese language will be hosted on *server B in Vietnam*. The content of these two websites has to be the same.

*Example:*
When I add an article in my wordpress website on server A the content has to be added to server B as a draft (not published) and a message has to be sent to the admin that they need to translate the content (in Vietnamese) and publish it, also the other way around.

Does anyone has experience with this and can help me out how to do this the best way?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I suggest get your RSS feed for site A

http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Feeds

Install this plugin to Site B

https://wordpress.org/plugins/rss-post-importer/

It has the option to grab the post and save as draft.  As for email you might need to add some code to send an email out when a new post is added.

```
function SendOutEmail($to, $subject, $message){

    global $wpdb;   
    add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type','set_mail_content_type' );
    $headers = 'From: no-reply <no-reply@example.com>';

    if (is_array($to)){
        foreach ($to as $email){
            wp_mail( $email, $subject, $message ,$headers);
        }
    }else{
        wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message ,$headers);
    }   
}

function set_mail_content_type(){
    return "text/html";
}
```